# Interesting tags on unanswered page point to question page

Tags: feature-request, tags, unanswered-questions

On the [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) page, there is on the right a list with "Unanswered Tags" and after that a list with my personal "Interesting Tags".

The unanswered tag list links to the unanswered page for that tag (e.g. [/unanswered/tagged/c#](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c%23)), while the interesting tag list links to all questions for that tag (e.g. [/questions/tagged/php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)).  Why is it done like this?

Would it be better to link the interesting tag list there to the unanswered pages instead? Is there an easy clickable path to the unanswered page of my favorite tags?

Answer (score 1):

The answer you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags).

That's the *my tags* page of the *Unanswered Questions*. You can click to the right *in your tags* tag links to filter them further.

Comment: I am talking about clicking to the page of 1 tag, not all my favorite tags.

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/php